# XPATH AND Condition on same Node

Tags: xml, xpath

this is a pretty simple question but I couldn't really find the correct result googling my problem.

I have this part of an xml document

```
<ProcessTypes>
     <ProcessType>
           <ID>DRUCK</ID>
     </ProcessType>
     <ProcessType>
           <ID>EBOX</ID>
     </ProcessType>
</ProcessTypes>
```

What would be the correct xpath expression to check if i have both ids "DRUCK" and "EBOX" in my xml file?

Comment: Show what you have already tried

Comment: Is your question answered?  If so, please accept an answer.  If not, please follow-up and explain.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath expression,

```
//ID="DRUCK" and //ID="EBOX"
```

will evaluate to true iff the XML document has an `ID` element with string value of `"DRUCK"` and an `ID` element with string value of `"EBOX"`.

---

Related, but not what was asked:

This XPath expression,

```
//ProcessType[ID="DRUCK" or ID="EBOX"]
```

will select all `ProcessType` elements with `ID` child elements with string values of either `"DRUCK"` or `"EBOX"`.